# AnyLogic: how to programmatically populate the Experiment page with information from Database?

Tags: anylogic

I have a Supply Chain simulation model where the names and locations of the warehouses are fed from the database that I have in the model. What I want to achieve is the following:

- When simulation starts, it copies the warehouse names from the DB and links them to the respective agents on the Experiment page. That is to say, let's say I have two warehouses: WH1, WH2. It should display theses as text on the Experiment page and when I click on WH1, it should take me to the respective agent. I have various plots inside the agents. The idea is to give the user the flexibility to be able to interact the model and take screenshots of the plots of whatever warehouses they wish.

Is this achievable in AnyLogic? If yes, how?

I tried to follow the recommendation of AnyLogic of creating interim variables, but can't really scale this up when I have hundreds of nodes.

[image]

Comment: Hey Yashar, why the need to do this via the Experiment? If you let the user see the Simulation animation, he/she can simply click on warehouse animations, like in all the example models...

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, I do have a GIS map with all the nodes..but sometimes there are hundreds of them and it is not convenient to find the warehouse you want. Instead, I would like to have an alphabetic list. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Sure, but you can do that list in the model itself as well, not the experiment screen, right? Use a replicated rectangle that "links" to the warehouse agent population with the "on click" code doing something like `myWarehousePop.get(index)._originVA.navigateTo()` ?

Comment: @Benjamin, thank you! Let me think about this.

Comment: @Benjamin, I am now able to create the text shapes, but cannot find how to set the "on click" properties (it should navigate to the agent graph). I am checking the AnyLogic ShapeText API, but can't find a method that would allow me to do this..

Comment: see screenshot in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue in the following manner. This creates the list of my agents, sorts them alphabetically by agentName in the `Main` agent.

1. Initializing the variables. Here `quotient` and `reminder` helps me to keep track of the columns; which of each should contain 60 agent names `numberPerColumn`.

```
int row=0;
int numberPerColumn=60;
int quotient=0;
int remainder=0;

int i1=0;
int newIndex=0;
```

2. Looping through the agents, creating ShapeText object to display their names.

```
while (i1<myAgents.size())
{
    int ii=i1;
    String myAgentName = myAgent.name;
    ShapeText text = new ShapeText(
            SHAPE_DRAW_2D, true, 300, 300.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
            black, myAgentName,
            font, ALIGNMENT_LEFT )
            
         {
//3. Overriding the onClick() method with the action that I want to happen upon click. In this case, it will take me to the `viewArea` inside `myAgent`.
    
        @Override
        public boolean onClick(double x, double y)
        {
        
            myAgent.viewArea.navigateTo();  
            return false;
        }};
        
//4. Setting the objects' position programmatically.
        
    quotient=i1/numberPerColumn;
    remainder=i1%numberPerColumn;
    text.setPos(quotient*250+50, -4550+remainder*20);

    presentation.add(text);
    
    i1+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write into the "on click" field of the replicated Text object:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I wanna do this programmatically..which seems an uneasy task?

Comment: ok, now I am lost again. Why programmatically? Just drag in 1 text object, replicate it x times (write `myPopulation.size()` in the "Replication" field) and use the `index` keyword in the "on click" field to write specific text in each text object replication, no?